# import another typescript module reside in node_modules

Tags: typescript

Is there anyway I can include other typescript modules (.ts) to current typescript project?

As far as I understand, there are two problems in the way.

- typescript requires a `.d.ts` file for all modules?
- duplicate `///ref<..>` tags in different modules will cause compiling error.

I was told this could be all resolved in `typescript@next` aka `typescript@2.0`.

But there was not any documentations/examples about it.

TYIA

Comment: your question is not clear. You can install external modules using `typings` and Definitely typed

Answer (score 0):

Just import them with the ES6 module syntax; no need for d.ts files if they're modules written in typescript.